# Suspicious static IPs in NAT table

Tags: networking, security, routing, nat

[image: Nat-Table]

I was doing some checking on my home network activity and in the process discovered some external IP address in my NAT table under the Inside Local column. I checked the table a couple of times over the course of the morning and each time found different entries. Usually no more than 1 or 2 but listed under the Inside Local column as a static entry. Whois showed the IPs to be from different locations; Turkey, S. Africa, USA, Germany, Romania etc. I did netstat against the corresponding port and in once instance found that it was using using Service Host as below.

[image: netstat check]

[image: Pid]

I don't know if this is normal behavior or not and I have no reason to believe that there is anything suspicious going on but I thought I would just put it out there to allay my fears.

Thanks for any help/advice/info in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Your question is very difficult to answer, because it is enormously broad. There is no doubt that we might be witnessing a compromised system, but how can we infer that from the info you provided? First, what does it mean you found external IP addresses under the NAT table? NAT is used for local devices, how can they have external IPs? Then, it is impossible to know whether these IPs correspond to a break-in or to a legitimate service, the least you should do is to provide the IPs in question. Please rewrite your post to make it possible for anyone to help you.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I'll do that once i get home. Yes of course Nat is for internal IPs or rather it provides the means for internal devices to communicate with external devices and that is exactly why I am concerned.

Comment: This needs more information, such as the _exact_ IP addresses in question. Your screenshot shows only a link-local IPv6 listener, so not sure how it can be related.

Comment: I added a link to the nat-table excerpt at the top of the original question. I can't find the specific one related to yesterday's post, I may not have saved it. As you will see in this example there is a static external IP where the list of internal IPs should show. I just want to know if this is normal.

Comment: Before I get asked. I'm not in Germany. My provider is Vodafone in Ireland.

Comment: no takers then?

Comment: Note that the "Inside global" column shows what appears to be a *local* address, and similarly the outside addresses seem to be swapped around. Perhaps this can give someone else a clue - the only explanation I can think of is that this device has a cosmetic bug when it shows you this table. May I ask what kind of device it is and if it is running recent firmware?

Comment: It's also strange that it is supposedly a static entry, but it will expire in 70 seconds?

Comment: Its a Huawei H658c home BB router. Firmware is updated by the BB provider.

Comment: Inside global address are what your address are seen as so that is normal. Inside local is your internal IP address. Inside global is the address that your ISP assigns to you whether it is static or dynamic.

Comment: @Geabhrog: "Inside global address are what your address are seen as so that is normal." but in the highlighted line of the nat table the inside global is  192.168.x.x and the inside local is 84.x.x.x so it seems to me that you agree that this is *not* normal ? (edit) Also: " Inside global is the address that your ISP assigns to you" but the table shows 5 different inside global addresses. Did you mean outside global, i.e. 109.76.x.x is the ip handed to you by your ISP. Then still, as I said in the highlighted line the outside local and global also seem to be swapped around?

Comment: @hertitu  The nat table contains tens if not hundreds of entries which refresh and change according to activity. I showed only 5 rows from the table which may or may not even exist anymore.

Comment: @Geabhrog: yes I understood that. What I'm saying (maybe I did not express myself too clearly) is that I see some anomalies in the table row that you are concerned about, so the one highlighted in yellow. The anomalies I see is that (A) the inside local is a public IP (as you noted) but the inside global is a private IP, so in other words they local and global seem to have been swapped around. And (B) the outside local is 109.76.3.189 and this address shows up as outside global in the 4 other lines, which makes me think the outside local and global are also swapped around.  Therefor...

Comment: ... I suspect that there is a cosmetic bug at play here, where the NAT table just shows certain addresses in the wrong column. However that still does not explain why you see a static connection that is not static.

Comment: @hertitu I thought it might be cosmetic or table corruption so I hard reset the router. Still the same after that. I'll do some more investigating this weekend if I get a chance and post the results. There are at least a dozen different systems on the internal network so I will turn all but one off and see what I get. Its a pity there is no way to SSH to these routers but unfortunately they are locked down afaik.